# Adding flickity Jquery plugin into Cargo site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little new to JS so please bear with me! I'm looking to add the Flickity carousel jQuery plugin to my cargo site, but can't get the page HTML to run the JS code. I believe my issue is in initializing the plugin in my HTML properly. Or possibly it's not valid JSON? (I'm new to JS so I'm not familiar with this). I've followed the Flickity installation steps from [here](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) **but Cargo is returning an error message and changing my attribute quotations** in the class  'data-flickity' options when saving my page HTML. I can see the carousel on my page but the "gallery-cells" are not in their proper place. Any help is much appreciated!

What the data-flickity HTML should look like:

```html
<div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true }'>
```

What my data-flickity HTML looks like:

```html
<div class="main-gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options="{ &quot;cellAlign&quot;: &quot;left&quot;, &quot;contain&quot;: true }">
```

And my my entire Div looks like:

```html
<div class="main-gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options="{ &quot;cellAlign&quot;: &quot;left&quot;, &quot;contain&quot;: true }">
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options="{ &quot;cellAlign&quot;: &quot;left&quot;, &quot;contain&quot;: true }">
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
  <div class="gallery-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you adding the Flickity code to the page? I have the feeling this is related to the CMS (Cargo), and how elements are added. Did you follow the steps in https://support.cargo.site/Custom-HTML to add your custom HTML?

Comment: SO perhaps you should vote to close due to that ambiguity in the question the OP has presented? Either way my suggestion to add clarity with a tag and error message by the OP seem to remain valid. I am going to remove all my comments and delete my answer and let you add any tags and answer this as you seem want to do so given your expertise here.

Comment: But you **added** the [[tag:cargo]] tag... I'm just trying to understand why you're undermining my cleanup efforts

Comment: There is only one "cargo" tag FWIW

Comment: Yes and that's expressly not about the site builder. Please read the tag description before you add any tag to a question. Especially if it's not your own question.